# Click on a specific ng-click in class using selenium protractor for ang js apps

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I have this in view source

```
<div class="row-fluid:>
<div class="span4">
<div class="well tile table-clickable" ng-click="move('mjass')">
<h3> Music Jass </h3>
<div class="row-fluid cellBody">
<div class="span5">
<i class=" some text"
</div>
```

There are 4 more div classes like the complete section above. One section for rock, one more section for classical so I want to click specific to a particular ng-Click. (only jass or rock or classical) for example I should click only "move('mjass') here

**In Protractor in using chrome driver with selenium in .js file**

I used, `element(by.className('well tile table-cilckable')).click()` and it worked successfully
But since there are lots of different classes, it always takes the first and clicks it, so instead i need to use both class and ng-click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a *partial match* on the `ng-click` attribute:

```
$("[ng-click*=mjass]").click();
```

where `$` is a shortcut to `element(by.css())`.

Or, you can add use an XPath expression and check the section title (a little bit less recommended by the [Style Guide](http://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide)):

```
element(by.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'table-clickable') and contains(h3, 'Music Jass')]")).click();
```

Comment: Sorry, this was my first post here and did not no how to accept the answer, no i have selected(clicked) the tick mark next to the answer. Hope this is correct. Thanks again!

Comment: @user7375268 thank you for respecting the rules and glad it worked for you.